# No way to align images to column top (multicol environnement)

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, multicol

I've been trying everything, but I'm lost right now, is there any way to really align image to the top of the column after a column break.

Here's an example code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent 
\lipsum[2]

\columnbreak

\noindent
\includegraphics{test}
\lipsum[2]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result I get :

[image: result]

Is there anyway to get a better layout (image aligned with top of first column?)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! What do you count as the top of the first column exactly?

Comment: You got it right... :-)

Comment: Actually, Harish Kumar got it right... ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add

```
\fbox{This is the top line of text and I want it to go on a bit.}
```

at the start of the first column, you can see that the image is perfectly aligned:

[image: aligned columns]

So some adjustments are needed to make things 'look right':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\hrule

\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent
\lipsum[2]
\columnbreak

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t,raise=-0.5\dp\strutbox]{example-image}
\lipsum[2]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I add something to your answer? You can delete it if you object, of course.

Comment: @cfr Please feel free. You are welcome and thanks. :-)

Comment: I shouldn't really have asked and then done it before waiting for a response, should I? Thanks for your understanding ;). [I don't mean: the mistake was in the asking.]

Comment: @cfr Not at all. You don't even have to ask anything but edit straight away. It is OK with me.

Comment: By the way, is there in any way to make this work in a figure environnement ? so that the image is referenced

Comment: @Arklost `multicol` and `figure` don't go well together. Load `caption` (or `capt-of`) package and use `\captionof{figure}{caption text}\label{fig}`.

Comment: Alright, I remember `multicol` doesn't like floats...